# Jackrabbit-oak build fails with mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, jackrabbit

I am trying to build the [Jackrabbit-oak project](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak) with `mvn clean install`, however, the build fails with the following error:

`[ERROR] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util: Version increase required; detected 1.2.0, suggested 1.3.0`.

I am using maven version 3.1 and Java version 7 (running on ubuntu 14.04 64bit), as shown in the maven version output below:

`Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 02:15:32+0000)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-41-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

### The detail build error is shown below:

```
...
[INFO] Building jar: /home/user/apache/jackrabbit-oak/oak-core/target/oak-core-1.4-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.3:baseline (baseline) @ oak-core ---
[INFO] artifact org.apache.jackrabbit:oak-core: checking for updates from apache.snapshots
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact org.apache.jackrabbit:oak-core' could not be retrieved from repository: apache.snapshots due to an error: repository.apache.org: Name or service not known
[INFO] artifact org.apache.jackrabbit:oak-core: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact org.apache.jackrabbit:oak-core' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known
[ERROR] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util: Version increase required; detected 1.2.0, suggested 1.3.0
[INFO] Baseline analysis complete, 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Oak Parent POM .................................... SUCCESS [7.662s]
[INFO] Oak Commons ....................................... SUCCESS [24.362s]
[INFO] Oak Blob Store .................................... SUCCESS [21.774s]
[INFO] Oak Cloud Blob Store .............................. SUCCESS [16.375s]
[INFO] Oak Core .......................................... FAILURE [25:51.533s]
[INFO] Oak JCR Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak upgrade ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak HTTP Binding .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Lucene ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Solr core ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Solr OSGi ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak External Authentication Support ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak LDAP Authentication Support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak TarMK Standby ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Remote API .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Runnable Jar .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Integration Tests for OSGi deployments ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Integration Tests ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak PojoSR ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak CUG ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oak Exercises ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jackrabbit Oak .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27:06.134s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 14 13:41:00 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/318M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.3:baseline (baseline) on project oak-core: Baseline failed, see generated report -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oak-core
```

It appears that the `maven-bundle-plugin` is causing the build to fail. Here is part of pom.xml file containing the plugin definition:

```
...
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <configuration>
        <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
        <instructions>
          <Bundle-Category>oak</Bundle-Category>
          <Bundle-DocURL>
            http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/
          </Bundle-DocURL>
          <Bundle-Vendor>The Apache Software Foundation</Bundle-Vendor>
        </instructions>
      </configuration>
      <!-- OAK-3041: use updated Bnd -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
          <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>baseline</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>baseline</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!--<comparisonVersion>1.2.0</comparisonVersion>-->
            <logResults>false</logResults>
            <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

...
```

Any idea why the build fails at this point?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that utilities package has been changed from version `1.2.0` to `1.3.0`. So changing the version of the [package](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/trunk/oak-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/util/package-info.java#L17) solves the problem.

This is answered in the [oak-dev mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.jackrabbit.oak.devel/8776).